# Switch i, j dots with an arrow

Tags: formatting, vector

I'm writing a Physics template and I came across this issue. I want the `i`, `j` to have vector lines instead of those dots. How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! `$\vec{\imath}$` and `$\vec{\jmath}$`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In maths mode, `\vec{}` will produce a vector arrow above a formula. To eliminate the dots on `i` and `j` use `\imath` and `\jmath` respectively.

So, for example, you can use `$\vec{\imath}$` or `$\vec{\jmath}$`.